# YouTube Data API does not return most popular videos list for Egypt and Yemen region

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to retrieve the list of most popular videos for several regions for research purpose. I am using YouTube Data API V3 and it does not return any results for Egypt and Yemen region even though there is if I browse the specific [url](https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending?gl=EG) from browser.

Here is the cURL from the editor in videos:list page-

```
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=EG&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Please try this [url](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%22%2C%22chart%22%3A%22mostPopular%22%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22EG%22%7D) and hit execute or past this [url](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatistics&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=50&regionCode=EG&key=AIzaSyDNTGIwf-TsAweg6-yFHWR4ZTkFPYlaeVE) directly in browser address bar. You will see result like this-

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "\"ksCrgYQhtFrXgbHAhi9Fo5t0C2I/oQ72O1DJZKbgBepvnImb6ljZwrw\"",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 0,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": []
}
```

This behavior has been consistent since I started collecting data a few days ago.

Can anybody please explain what is going on and why?

Comment: you may want to check around on the bug forumn https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B  its probably already there.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks. I haven't seen any similar issue posted browsing that url. I will browse some more.